# How to know SQL Server backup file BLOCKSIZE from .bak?

Tags: sql-server

When I am trying to restore filelist from azure blob container I get an error.

```
command executing:
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM URL = N'http://<azureaccount>/<container>/mybak.bak' 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycreds'
```

error:

```
Msg 3268, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Cannot use the backup file 'http://<azureaccount>/<container>/mybak.bak' because it was originally formatted with sector size 512 and is now on a device with sector size 65536.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

How to know the BLOCKSIZE value from .bak file?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible, but if it is you would get it using [RESTORE Statements - HEADERONLY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I looked around and was not able to find an existing answer, or anything that explained your issue in detail that seemed to match your problem.